# Xamarin Forms Present a Page from Right to Left

Tags: xamarin.forms

Actually I am trying to show a Master Detail Page with Menu button on right side. I am not getting any option to present a Page modally from right to left and same dismiss also left to right. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: You can refer this link http://www.allenhashkey.com/mobile-development/xamarin-forms-custom-master-detail-rightleft/

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlowDirection

```
<MasterDetailPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="RTL.MasterDetailPage"
    Padding="25"
    FlowDirection="RightToLeft">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title=" ">
            <StackLayout>
                <Button Text="Menu item" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage>
            <Label Text="My page"/>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

https://blog.xamarin.com/right-to-left-localization-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Better work around is,

Disable Navigation tool bar,

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Create custom tool bar with Hamburger image,

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image Source="hamburger" Margin="2,0,0,0" HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="25">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ToggleMasterCommand}" CommandParameter="1"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label Text="Header text" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Image  Source="notification" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding NotificationCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>
```

Apply FlowDirection for each page. either Xaml or code behind through Visual Element

You can see a demo for setting Visual Element through code behind [here](http://xamarinindia.blogspot.com/2018/11/xamarin-forms-rtl-right-to-left-support.html)